# Creating a custom ArrayAdapter using extends ArrayAdapter<Item>

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-arrayadapter

I've been trying to learn about custom adapters, namely the ArrayAdapter.

I've been trying to follow the examples like the one [here](http://sujewan.blogspot.com.au/2013/08/9-android-custom-gridview.html) or [here](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/07/custom-grid-view-example-in-android.html) and several others but I keep getting stuck with the `ArrayAdapter<Item>` part. Android Studio won't allow it and want's to change it to `ClipData.Item`

I've searched everywhere for a reason why but can't find anything.

The end game for me is to be able to have a custom adapter that insets images into a gridview with the gridview.add() method but all the tuts I can find want to use `ArrayAdapter<Item>`

Can anyone shed any light on this for me please?

Comment: post the "troubling" code

Comment: It's just a copy-paste of the links I have in the question

Comment: I'm guessing it's trying to import the wrong class, I sure hope you have your own Item class to import.

Answer (score 0):

I was following the 2nd tutorial I posted, which makes no reference of the fact that you have to create your own Item class. The 1st tutorial shows that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a full example for a custom adapter [example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) i hope it will help you. And i suggest that you first use a simple custom adapter with 
 `ArrayAdapter <string>` so you can easily move to `ArrayAdapter <object>`